# Cross-database views and mirroring in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view, mirroring, cross-database

I have a question about mirroring and cross-db views.
We have a view in database X which references database Y on the same server S1.
The databases X & Y are both mirrored onto another server S2.
The problem is: if db X fails over to S2, the view which references db Y is now looking on S2, but db Y may not have failed over.
What is the best way around this? Can you create a mirrored couple, so that if 1 on the dbs in the couple fails over, the other one does too?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We detect that the database has failed and [manually failover](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179481.aspx) the second database. This [article](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1564)  will likely help; basically it is a hack on the failover of the first database in the witness that lets you trigger a failover of the second database.

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1564

Comment: Thanks - should be just what I need

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to SQL 2012 you can use the Always on Availability Groups function to group databases for this very purpose.